# Differentiability of a series

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the following theorem:

Theorem: Let $f_n$ be differentiable on an interval $[a,b]$ and assume $\sum f_n' (x)$ converges uniformly to a limit $g(x)$ on $[a,b]$. If there exists at least one $x_0 \in [a,b]$ where $\sum f_n (x_0)$ converges then the series $\sum f_n (x)$ converges uniformly to a differentiable function $f$ with $f' = g$ on $[a,b]$.

---

Is it possible to apply theorem 6.4.3. to an interval consisting of one point only: $[a,a]= \{a\}$?

Comment: What exactly is $h$? If it is the function from the page to which you created a link, then $h$ is not differentiable in some points.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for your comment. I edited the question. I replaced $s$ (on Wikipedia) by $h$ in my question. I now also changed the question to reflect my progress on this problem.

Comment: Differentiabiltity in a point only makes sense if you have some kind of neighbourhood of that point where the function is defined. And Theorem 6.4.3 is in fact only applicable on intervals where all the functions $f_n$ are differentiable on all of the interval. This is only useful if this interval has nonempty interior.

Comment: @Thomas But... "is only useful": is it equivalent to saying the theorem 6.4.3. fails if $a=b$?

Comment: Usually differentiability is only defined on interior points. There are means to extend this to the boundary of intervals or the boundary of open set in higher dimensions, and even to more general sets, but in a textbook the definition assumes almost certainly intervals without nonempty interior as domain of definition for differentiable functions. This means for your theorem 6.4.3 that it simply does not apply.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for your reply, I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: @Thomas But I don't understand it. The $f_n$ are all defined on $\mathbb R$ they're just not differentiable everywhere. So I can still apply the definition of derivative to compute the derivative at $a$.

Comment: In the formulation of your questino (what remains of it) your are talking about $f_n:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If $a=b$, then applying the theorem does not make sense. If $a<c < b$ and the $f_n$ are _all_differentiable on the whole of $[a,b]$, the theorem applies and (assuming all prerequisites are met) the limit is differentiable. In that case you can, of course, specialise and claim it is differentiable in $c$, but this would just be a weaker claim than what you can get. The problem with your initial example was that the $f_n$ were not _simultaneously_ differentiable on a given open set.